# How to display video from firebase storage url in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I tried to fetch data from firestore in there has video ulr also fetched all the data from firestore and it's display nicely but video preview not show in page so i wrote a **"print('data[index].url ${data[index].url}');"** then url printed in console when click that opening in web browser. **I want to convert that to video and display in page.** when playing without sounds that's better because this is list view page.

code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kathaappctse/screens/therapy/therapist/tutorialModel.dart';
import 'package:kathaappctse/screens/therapy/therapist/viewOneTutorial.dart';

import '../../login&signup&splashscreen/loginScreen.dart';
import 'ViewOneTutorialUpdate.dart';
import 'addtutorials.dart';



class AllTutorialAdminScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AllTutorialAdminScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AllTutorialAdminScreen> createState() => _AllTutorialAdminScreenState();
}

class _AllTutorialAdminScreenState extends State<AllTutorialAdminScreen> {
  List<Tutorial> tutorial = [];


  // fetch data from collection
  @override
  Future<List<Tutorial>> fetchRecords() async {
    var records = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('articles').get();
    return mapRecords(records);
  }
  List<Tutorial> mapRecords(QuerySnapshot<Object?>? records) {
    var _list = records?.docs
        .map(
          (tutorial) => Tutorial(
        id: tutorial.id,
            topic: tutorial['topic'],
            type: tutorial["type"],
            description: tutorial["description"],
            url: tutorial["url"],
      ),
    )
        .toList();

    return _list ?? [];
  }

  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Scrollbar(
        isAlwaysShown: true,
        child: SizedBox(
          width: width * 1,
          height: height * 1,
          child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('articles').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              } else {
                List<Tutorial> data = mapRecords(snapshot.data);
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {


                    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(data[index].url);
                    print('_controller ${_controller}');
                    print('data[index].url ${data[index].url}');
                    return SizedBox(
                      height:  height * 0.20,
                      child: Card(
                        color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.4),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.redAccent,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(
                              child:  Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 1),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                                        child: Container(
                                          color: Colors.cyan,
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                            height: 50,
                                            width: 50,
                                            child:  SizedBox(
                                              width: 50,
                                              height: 50,
                                              child: VideoPlayer( VideoPlayerController.network(data[index].url)),
                                            )

                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),


                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
            },
          ),

        ),
      ),



    );
  }
}
```

model

```
import 'dart:convert';

Tutorial TutorialFromJson(String str) => Tutorial.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String TutorialToJson(Tutorial data) => json.encode(data.toJson());
class Tutorial {
  Tutorial({
    required this.id,
    required this.topic,
    required this.type,
    required this.description,
    required this.url

  });
  String id;
  String topic;
  String type;
  String description;
  String url;


  factory Tutorial.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Tutorial(
    id: json["id"] ?? "",
    topic: json["topic"] ?? "",
    type: json["type"] ?? "",
    url: json["url"]?? "",
      description: json["description"]?? ""
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "topic": topic,
    "type": type,
    "url": url,
    'description' : description

  };
}
```

how to solve this error and convert url to video and display without voice?

Comment: I don't see where you have initialized your video player? 
Once you assign the VideoController you should initialize it using
`_controller.initialize()`

Comment: @MaheshJamdade i added in the  "itemBuilder: (context, index) {" then show  this error "LateInitializationError: Field '_controller@40508867' has not been initialized."

Comment: initialize controller in your initState ` _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(data[index].url);`

see this example https://pub.dev/packages/video_player#example
Also this code sample https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59715#issuecomment-871419610  if you are trying to reinitialize video in runtime just avoid using streamBuilder for now and use setState (based on the discussion in that thread).